# Sistema de Parcelas Mysql Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Preciso de um sistema que cadastre várias parcelas de titulo em meu BD Mysql
tenho este codigo abaixo que cadastra e repete o insert de acordo com qtde de parcelas informada, porém acontece que ao escolher a data com dia 30, chega em fevereiro ele pula o mes e vai para 2 de março.. onde esta o erro?

```
public function cad_despesa_funciona() {

    $nParcelas = '3';
    $dataPrimeiraParcela = '30/12/2017';
    //$dataemissao = date('Y-m-d');
    //$ndocumento = 'ndcu';
    //$titulo = 'titulo';
    //$valor = '500.00';

if($dataPrimeiraParcela != null && $nParcelas !=null){
    $dataPrimeiraParcela = explode('/',$dataPrimeiraParcela);
    $dia = $dataPrimeiraParcela[0];
    $mes = $dataPrimeiraParcela[1];
    $ano = $dataPrimeiraParcela[2];
} else {
    $dia = date("d");
    $mes = date("m");
    $ano = date("Y");
}

for($x = 1; $x <= $nParcelas; $x++){
     $dt_parcelas[$x] = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+".$x." month",mktime(0, 0,0,$mes,$dia,$ano)));
    }
    var_dump($nParcelas);
    foreach ($dt_parcelas as $vencimento)
    {
        $dados = array(
            'titulo' => 'teste titulo',
            'ndocumento' => '123',
            'datavencimento' => $vencimento,
            'parcela' => '123',
            'formadepgto' => '2',
            'valor' => '50.00',
            'dataemissao' => '2017-10-25',
            'planodecontas' => '2',
            'status' => 'aberto',
            'parcelaatual' => '2'
        );
    $this->db->insert('sis_despesas', $dados);
    }
}
```

Tenho Esse outro código tbm, só que não consegui adaptá-lo no codeigniter, no php direto consegui trabalhar com ele, inclusive se não me engano ele pega o ultimo dia de fevereiro, ao invés de pegar o próximo mes, esse é um sistema de mensalidade, nao pode ficar 1 mes sem.

```
    $parcelas = '3';
    $datavenc = '2017-12-30';
    $datavencimento = Array(date('Y' , strtotime($datavenc)), date('m' , strtotime($datavenc)), date('d' , strtotime($datavenc)));
    $data_array = Array($datavencimento[0], $datavencimento[1], $datavencimento[2]);
    $n = $data_array[1]-1;
    $v_i = $n;

for($i = 0; $i < $parcelas; $i++) {

    $v_i++;
    $v = strtotime ( '+'.$i.' month' , strtotime(implode("-", $data_array))) ;
    $nd = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $v );
    $p = explode("-", $nd);

if($v_i <= 12) {

    $base_mes = date("Y-m-t", strtotime($nd));
    $forma_data = $p[0].'-'.$v_i.'-01';
    $ultimo_dia_do_mes = date("Y-m-t", strtotime($forma_data));
    $b1 = explode("-", $base_mes); // EXPLODE DO BASE MES
    $b2 = explode("-", $ultimo_dia_do_mes); // EXPLODE DO ULTIMO DIA DO MÊS

if($b1[2]!=$b2[2]) {
        $gravarData = $b2[0] . "-" . $b2[1] . "-" . $b2[2] . " 00:00:00";
    } else {
        $gravarData = $b1[0] . "-" . $b1[1] . "-" . $data_array[2].  " 00:00:00";
    }
    //AQUI EU COLOCO O INSERT PARA O BD
    }
else {
} 
} 
}
```

Comment: Seu codigo esta completo? estou sentindo falta de onde a variavel $vencimento é carregada e o complemento do FOR.
Todo o problema é que se voce dar um insert no banco de dados de um dia que não existe no mês então o banco vai colocar a diferença dos dias a maior para o proximo mês, ou seja, se voce colcoar dia 31/06/2018 ele vai inserir no banco dia 01/07/2018.

Comment: Estava incompleto, não tinha percebido, eu tinha colocado o codigo entre <code>, agora vi que era so dar uns espaços antes q resolvia..

Comment: Pode mostrar uma chave da várialvel `$dados` ? `print_r($dados);`